# Tried installing Ubuntu for dual boot. Now Windows won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, boot-repair

I am trying to dual boot my older HP ProBook with Windows 10 installed. I made a bootable USB with Ubuntu 23.10 on it. It would not let me install it on the hard drive when I booted Ubuntu. It said there was not enough space on the disk. I exited out of the Ubuntu USB. I then tried to restart the laptop and BIOS told me no bootable media was found on the hard drive.

I have researched this extensively on my own. I made a bootable Windows USB with Windows Media Creation tool on another PC, but my laptop isn't reading it for some reason. I am writing you from the live USB boot of Ubuntu. Here is the output from Boot-Repair. I ran it once already and Windows still won't boot

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda6 starts 
                       at sector 1. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                       sda6 starts at sector 621219840.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: L77 Ver. 01.50(1.50) from Hewlett-Packard
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery

04fb9982cb9d93492d3220cf08f03f02   sda7/Boot/bootx64.efi
04fb9982cb9d93492d3220cf08f03f02   sda7/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
8ea8644096bf0b8227e6541e9a790f8c   sda7/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda6    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda7    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda6    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda7    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : not--sepboot, no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda6    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda7    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 298.09 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x026b3a65
     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1            2048   1023999   1021952   499M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2         1024000 557522943 556498944 265.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3       557522944 625141759  67618816  32.2G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
sda5       557523008 621217855  63694848  30.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda6       621219840 623192063   1972224   963M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda7  *    623192064 625141759   1949696   952M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
Disk sdb: 114.6 GiB, 123048296448 bytes, 240328704 sectors
Disk identifier: ABBD44C4-640C-4CEA-ACCB-CA38273F602E
       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sdb1       64   9788791   9788728   4.7G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  9788792   9798859     10068   4.9M EFI System
sdb3  9798860   9799459       600   300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  9801728 240328640 230526913 109.9G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________


blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
├─sda1 ntfs     D8126BFC126BDE4E                     026b3a65-01                          System Reserved          
├─sda2 ntfs     10186DC8186DAE02                     026b3a65-02                          Windows                  
├─sda3                                               026b3a65-03                                                   
├─sda5                                               026b3a65-05                                                   
├─sda6 ntfs     01DA7AB47EFF8D70                     026b3a65-06                                                   
└─sda7 vfat     BDC0-A99C                            026b3a65-07                                                   
sdb    iso9660  2024-02-20-19-39-27-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1 iso9660  2024-02-20-19-39-27-00               abbd44c4-640c-4cea-acca-ca38273f602e Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2 vfat     927C-33D8                            abbd44c4-640c-4cea-acc9-ca38273f602e ESP                      Appended2
├─sdb3                                               abbd44c4-640c-4cea-acc8-ca38273f602e                          Gap1
└─sdb4 ext4     e2172291-2d0a-45e6-b7e6-dc32de5e44c8 a31da1c9-68c9-3b45-8f38-e9299b4aaf29 writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                                                     466.7M   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2                                                     114.1G  57% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda6                                                       950M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
/dev/sda7                                                     923.2M   3% /mnt/boot-sav/sda7
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom
efivarfs                                                       83.3K  29% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1                                                     fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda2                                                     fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda6                                                     fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda7                                                     vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix
```

Comment: It looks like you have Windows installed in old BIOS/MBR configuration. But have an UEFI system. Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012, so did you install Windows yourself? But you cannot mix BIOS boot with UEFI boot on same drive and should not mix, anyway. Since Windows is on MBR(msdos) drive, difficult to convert to UEFI as change to gpt would totally erase drive. Make sure system is in BIOS mode & see if Windows boots. Use Windows to shrink NTFS partition to make unallocated for Ubuntu. If 4GB or less of RAM, better to use lightweight flavor.